# trouble when parsing json response to java model with Gson

Tags: java, gson

I have a little problem when trying to parse this JSON that I got when calling locationIQ API

```
[  
   {  
      "place_id":"208857340",
      "licence":"https:\/\/locationiq.com\/attribution",
      "osm_type":"relation",
      "osm_id":"7444",
      "boundingbox":[  
         "48.8155755",
         "48.902156",
         "2.224122",
         "2.4697602"
      ],
      "lat":"48.8566101",
      "lon":"2.3514992",
      "display_name":"Paris, \u00cele-de-France, France m\u00e9tropolitaine, France",
      "class":"place",
      "type":"city",
      "importance":0.97893459932191,
      "icon":"https:\/\/locationiq.org\/static\/images\/mapicons\/poi_place_city.p.20.png"
   },
   {  
      "place_id":"208880706",
      "licence":"https:\/\/locationiq.com\/attribution",
      "osm_type":"relation",
      "osm_id":"71525",
      "boundingbox":[  
         "48.8155755",
         "48.902156",
         "2.224122",
         "2.4697602"
      ],
      "lat":"48.85881005",
      "lon":"2.32003101155031",
      "display_name":"Paris, \u00cele-de-France, France m\u00e9tropolitaine, France",
      "class":"boundary",
      "type":"administrative",
      "importance":0.97893459932191,
      "icon":"https:\/\/locationiq.org\/static\/images\/mapicons\/poi_boundary_administrative.p.20.png"
   },
  {...}
]
```

I have created 2 java class model,
one named Location who only have an arrayList

```java
ArrayList<LocationData> locations;
```

and another one who is the java description of what i got in my response

```java
    @SerializedName("place_id")
    private String placeId;
    @SerializedName("licence")
    private String license;
    @SerializedName("osm_type")
    private String osmType;
    @SerializedName("osm_id")
    private String osmId;
    @SerializedName("boundingbox")
    private ArrayList<String> geoLocation;
    @SerializedName("lat")
    private String lat;
    @SerializedName("lon")
    private String lon;
    @SerializedName("display_name")
    private String displayName;
    @SerializedName("class")
    private String classType;
    @SerializedName("type")
    private String type;
    @SerializedName("importance")
    private String importance;
    @SerializedName("icon")
    private String icon;
```

but when i try to do `Gson.fromJson(myStringResponse, Locations.class);`

I have **IllegalStateException** `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $`

I tried to replace Locations.class by LocationData but that didn't change anything.

So if you have any hint.

Comment: The error tells you what the problem is: you're deserializing a JSON array, containing objects that can be mapped to LocationData. You're not deserializing an object. The class `Locations` is useless, since it doesn't match with your JSON structure, which is just a single array. You want to create a List<LocationData>: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Collections-Examples

Comment: that was it thank, i have replace Gson.fromJson(myStringResponse, Locations.class); by fromJson(locationIQResponse, LocationData[].class); and that ok

Answer (score 0):

If your Locations.class, LocationData.class is required deserialised object class then, your json object should be like below, 
At the root element is a JSONArray which contains the member named locations.This JSONArray contains another object which is locationdata with different data members like place_id, licence, etc.,

```
{  
  "locations":[  
    {  
     "place_id":"208857340",
     "licence":"https:\/\/locationiq.com\/attribution",
     "osm_type":"relation",
     "osm_id":"7444",
     "boundingbox":[  
        "48.8155755",
        "48.902156",
        "2.224122",
        "2.4697602"
     ],
     "lat":"48.8566101",
     "lon":"2.3514992",
     "display_name":"Paris, \u00cele-de-France, France m\u00e9tropolitaine, France",
     "class":"place",
     "type":"city",
     "importance":0.97893459932191,

      "icon":"https:\/\/locationiq.org\/static\/images\/mapicons\/poi_place_city.p.20.png"
   },
  {  
     "place_id":"208880706",
     "licence":"https:\/\/locationiq.com\/attribution",
     "osm_type":"relation",
     "osm_id":"71525",
     "boundingbox":[  
        "48.8155755",
        "48.902156",
        "2.224122",
        "2.4697602"
     ],
     "lat":"48.85881005",
     "lon":"2.32003101155031",
     "display_name":"Paris, \u00cele-de-France, France m\u00e9tropolitaine, France",
     "class":"boundary",
     "type":"administrative",
     "importance":0.97893459932191,
     "icon":"https:\/\/locationiq.org\/static\/images\/mapicons\/poi_boundary_administrative.p.20.png"
  }
  ]
}
```

I am converting json string back to java pojo object.

```
try {
        BufferedReader myStringResponse = new BufferedReader(
                 new FileReader("E:\\RunningApp\\file1.json"));
        Locations locationDesirialize = gson.fromJson(myStringResponse, Locations.class);

        locationDesirialize.getLocations().forEach(location ->{
            System.out.println("getPlaceId "+location.getPlaceId());
        } );

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```